# Java using Jackson for Json coversion from Json into object and ignoring optional field

Tags: java, json

I am doing a conversion from Json to Java pojo.  I have several optional field in my json that I want to have the flexibility to do a getter and not get nullpointerException.  Can you please tell me how to code this in oder to avoid null pointer exception on optional field.  I have read to use Option.of but It does not work it.  Thanks

Comment: use @JsonIgnoreProperty for optional field.

Answer (score 0):

In this case yiu can try @JsonIgnore or custom deserialize.

Loot at this link: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization